# fopen non-ascii character error

Tags: c++, c, unicode, fopen

i cannot use fopen on files includes in their name some characters (example : ş, ç, ı)
how can i use fopen on these files ?
i'm using vc++ 6 (i have to) and c language.
when i was trying to use _wfopen it's never open any file.

Comment: Need more details, was errno set after the call to _wfopen()?  How were you trying to read data from the returned file handle (if at all)?

Comment: Please post your code with _wfopen so we might be able to figure out why it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Convert your pathname to UTF-16 (probably using [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072.aspx)) and use [`GetShortPathNameW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989.aspx) to get a path you can pass to `fopen`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have wchar_t (it's a compiler setting) and make sure you're passing in a wchar_t * and not a char * to _wfopen.